# Export/Import xml

Tags: migration

I am trying to migrate my website from my localhost to a server.

I am trying to export data from the export plugin of wordpress and import the xml file into the other database. That data importation always fails at step 2. Few data are imported and then the plugin get stuck.

After looking a inside the data, I have noticed that the exported xml has extra data. For example I have an original location `25 de mayo` and in the exported xml has been modified in `c de mayo`. Seems that wordpress has some problem with numbers. The version of wordpress are the same on the to environments. I have a lot of data to import. I changed the name of prefix of db for security reasons.

I have tried to import data with `mysqldump` and `mysql` changing all prefix in the tables, but for some reason the server stop works in this case. I restored the db, but still can't import the whole data. How can I resolve this mess?

Comment: Do you have any custom post types or taxonomies? Does the issue persist if you deactivate all plugins and use the default theme? Can you please add the name of step 2 to your question? Not everybody can install a blank WordPress and fire up the importer to remember what step 2 was

Comment: what it is really important are the custyom taxonomy. the web site is still in development, so no users stuff inside. the step 2 is final step, it has to tell me that every thing goes fine. I am trying to split the xml in smaller chunks. Seem in this way more custom taxonomies are uploaded.

Comment: And the plugin that implements the custom taxonomy is activate on both sites when you export and import?

Comment: The special characters in the Spanish language (n tilde, grave/acute accents) might be the issue. You mention using mysqldump (which is the way I'd do it) and "changing all prefixes". What does that last part mean? Why do you need to change prefixes? Do you mean site name prefixes?

Comment: @TomJNowell I am using the native funtion of wordpress to eport/import.

Comment: @barrycarter If I split the whole xml into smaller chunks, the importations succeed, but taxonomies result broken. I guess the cause may be a sort of queries quota.

Comment: How do you split the XML into smaller chunks? A section of an XML file is not itself an XML file.

Comment: But Emanuele, can you confirm that the code implementing your custom taxonomy is active on both sites ***before*** you import/export, not ***after***? And again, what is step 2 of the importer called?

Comment: @TomJNowell yes i do. the step 2 is simply the returning message of import routine. It has to tell me that everything is gone fine.

Comment: But what is step 2?

Comment: step 2 is the end of the process. All the process is in `tools->wordpress`